# $$hashKey match and selected value for select menu

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to set selected option for the select menu but its not working because data that I am sending to `ng-model` has different `$$hashKey` from data in the select menu and `$$hashKey` holding for values.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selManga" ng-options="manga.seri for manga in mangalar"> 
<option value="">Manga Seçin</option> 
</select>
<select ng-change="selPage = 0" ng-model="selChapter" ng-options="selManga.randomword.indexOf(chapter) as chapter.klasor for chapter in selManga.randomword"> 
<option value="">Bölüm</option> 
</select>
<select ng-model="selPage" ng-options="selManga.randomword[selChapter].yol.indexOf(page) as selManga.randomword[selChapter].yol.indexOf(page) + 1 for page in selManga.randomword[selChapter].yol">
</select>
```

I google it to get around with this people says `track by` but I have to use `as`. So is there a another way to get around it?

Selected value for first select menu is working but second one is not working. Here is plunker.http://plnkr.co/edit/3V8JSF2AU01ZZNPfLECd?p=info

```
.controller('nbgCtrl',function  ($scope, MMG, $stateParams) {
var milo = $stateParams.serix;
var musti = $stateParams.klasor;
MMG.adlar.success(function(loHemen) {
    var i, miloMangaInArray;
    for (i=0; i<loHemen.length; i++) {
        if (loHemen[i].seri===milo) {
            miloMangaInArray = loHemen[i];
            break;
        }
    };
    var a;
    for (a=0; a<miloMangaInArray.randomword.length; a++) {
        if(miloMangaInArray.randomword[a].klasor===musti) {
            break;

        }
    }
$scope.mangalar = loHemen; //JSON Data
$scope.selManga = $scope.mangalar[i]; // First select menu's ng-model and its working.
$scope.selChapter = $scope.mangalar[i].randomword[a]; //Second select menu's ng-model and its not working due to no matching JSON data.
});

$scope.next = function (manga, chapter, page) {
    var nextPage = page + 1;
    if (angular.isDefined(manga.randomword[chapter].yol[nextPage])) {
        $scope.selPage = nextPage;
    } else if (angular.isDefined(manga.randomword[chapter + 1])) {
        $scope.selChapter = chapter + 1;
        $scope.selPage = 0;
    }};

})
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please add some entries of your data for `mangalar`? With-out data it is difficult to re-create your problem. I have created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8wbhb8e/) but that's probably not exactly what you're looking for but I couldn't make it better because I don't know what's in `randomword`.

Comment: @AWolf [JSON Data](http://api.baskimerkeziankara.com/mangalar?callback=JSON_CALLBACk)

Comment: OK, thanks for the data. But it is still not clear how it should work. First combo box selects `seri` for the second combo and in the second you'd like to select `klasor`. After that selection you want to display all images stored in `yol` array for `seri` with that `klasor`. Is that right?

Comment: @AWolf Here I create it plnkr.  [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/foFjixSEyXtoEeP9uSHP?p=info) and here is example of what I want to achieve. [Example website](http://www.mangaoku.net/Priest/145/2)

Comment: @AWolf Here is updated plunker.http://plnkr.co/edit/3V8JSF2AU01ZZNPfLECd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should embrace the AngularJS way of handling models and bindings.  So, instead of keeping track of all the different indexes through your view code, you can simply let `ng-select` assign references to parts of your model (via `ng-model`).  By changing the HTML and controller slightly, you can simplify some of the code, and it will actually work, too.

First, make a shared `$scope.model = {…}` object available on the `$scope`.  Then, change the HTML to

```
<select ng-model="model.selManga" ng-options="manga.seri for manga in mangalar">
  <option value="">Manga Seçin</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="model.selChapter" ng-options="chapter.klasor for chapter in model.selManga.randomword" ng-change="model.selPage = model.selChapter.yol[0]">
  <option value="">Bölüm</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="model.selPage" ng-options="page as model.selChapter.yol.indexOf(page) + 1 for page in model.selChapter.yol">
</select>
<img class="picture" ng-src="http://baskimerkeziankara.com/{{model.selPage}}" ng-click="next(model.selPage)">
```

After that, change the controller is changed accordingly:

```
.controller('nbgCtrl', function($scope, MMG, $stateParams) {
    var model = {
      selManga: undefined,
      selChapter: undefined,
      selPage: undefined
    };
    $scope.model = model;

    MMG.adlar.success(function _init(loHemen) {
      for (var i = 0; i < loHemen.length; i++) {
        if (loHemen[i].seri === $stateParams.serix) {
          model.selManga = loHemen[i];
          break;
        }
      }

      for (var a = 0; a < model.selManga.randomword.length; a++) {
        if (model.selManga.randomword[a].klasor === $stateParams.klasor) {
          model.selChapter = model.selManga.randomword[a];
          break;
        }
      }

      model.selPage = model.selChapter.yol[0];

      $scope.mangalar = loHemen;
    });

    $scope.next = function _next(page) {
      var pageIndex = model.selChapter.yol.indexOf(page);

      if (angular.isDefined(model.selChapter.yol[pageIndex + 1])) {
        model.selPage = model.selChapter.yol[pageIndex + 1];
      } else {
        var chapterIndex = model.selManga.randomword.indexOf(model.selChapter);

        if (angular.isDefined(model.selManga.randomword[chapterIndex])) {
          pageIndex = 0;

          model.selChapter = model.selManga.randomword[chapterIndex + 1];
          model.selPage = model.selChapter.yol[pageIndex];
        }
      }
      console.log('manga', model.selManga.seri, 
                  'chapter', model.selChapter.klasor,
                  'selPage', pageIndex + 1);
    };
  })
```

I've created a forked Plunker that shows how this works (and this solution actually works): http://plnkr.co/edit/2aqCUAFUwwXuGQHpuooj

Comment: Okay thank you for this its works perfect. Could you add one more thing that is the setting selected value for third select menu. State `oku` has url with `url: "/oku/:serix/:klasor/:page"` so if url comes with `page:3` it has load page 3. Can you do that? Here is the plunker that I added onyl page parameter to url. http://plnkr.co/edit/rl7bIQIIEH8KZu7B4awG

Comment: I solved my problem. I simply add `$stateParams.page` to `model.selPage = model.selChapter.yol[page - 1]`. Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome.  Nice to hear that it worked out well for you.

Answer (score 4):

Dude here you go, a js fiddle for the solution
http://jsfiddle.net/yw248mfu/2/

the method I used here is indexOf to get the index of the page in the array for the last select only ,,

and this is not the best solution as it will have to apply index of every time the digest loop run ,,
I can think of a number of different solutions to this ,,

1- you can extract the id of the page from the name of the image itself

2- you can map the pages array to be a list of objects with the following schema

```
[{"index":1,"img":"00.jpg"},{"index":2,"img":"01.jpg"},{"index":3,"img":"02.jpg"}]
```

you can do the second option with this piece of code

```
pages.map(function(d,i){return {"index":i,"img":d};});
```

**crouch74**